# objects.filter to get if string is contained in one or other field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter my clients with a query. **The user can look for the cif code and the client name writing in the same field so I can't know if he's looking for one thing or another**.
I'm trying to figure it out how to filter in both fields without excluding the other.
I'll try give an example:

I have this on my client table:

```
[
    {
        "company_name":"Best Bar EUW",
        "cif":"ABCD1234"
    },
    {
        "company_name":"Word Bar EEUU",
        "cif":"POIU4321"
    },
    {
        "company_name":"Not a bad bar",
        "cif":"MNVB1321"
    }
]
```

Now I want to look for the "EE" string: the result that I want is the second object but the string "EE" is not included in the "cif" so it won't give me the result I want because it is included in one field but not in the other.

This is my Client model:

```
class Client(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Model definition for Client."""

    company_name = models.CharField("Nombre de la empresa", max_length=150, default="Nombre de empresa", null=False, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cif = models.CharField("CIF", null=False, default="", max_length=50)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField('consumptions.Platform', verbose_name=("Plataformas"))
    dateadded = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de inserción", default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

What can I do with this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***logical OR*** with [***`contains`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains) lookup

```
from django.db.models import Q

search_keyword = "EE"
or_expression = Q(company_name__contains=search_keyword) | Q(cif__contains=search_keyword)
Client.objects.filter(or_expression)
```

Comment: that was the problem I was talking about: if I look for EEUU it wont give me the second result because it is included in company_name but NOT in cif

Comment: What is you search string? In OP you have mentioned it as ***`EE`***, not `EEUU`

Comment: That's irrelevant, "EE" and "EEUU" is included in "company_name" of the second value but NOT in cif.

Comment: Then, you only need to look into `company_name` field. (Updated the answer)

Comment: No, because the user could want to look for the cif instead of the company name and it is the same issue. If the user looks for the code, for example "POIU4" and that code is not included in the company name it won't show me that value as a result. Remember that the same field is used for looking for the cif and the company name.

Comment: That means the ***search keyword*** can be found in either `company_name` or `cif` field. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly! the problem is that if it finds it in one and it is not in the other it won't give me that value as result.

Comment: Perfect! worked like a charm: just updated this line to look for the string contained instead of the same string: or_expression = Q(company_name__contains=query) | Q(cif__contains=query)

Comment: bit confused, is `search_keyword` not same as `query` ? I don't get that

Comment: yeah yeah is the same, i'm just using query instead of search_keyword, the problem was that we had cif=query instead of cif__contains=query